# Kolmogorov complexity of tuples

Tags: information-theory, encoding-scheme, kolmogorov-complexity

Exercise 14.1 of Elements of Information Theory asks us to prove that there is a constant c such that

$$K(x,y)\leq K(x) +K(y)+c$$

for all binary strings $x,y$. Intuitively this seems true. Just write a program that first runs the program that $p_x$ that outputs $x$. Then the program $p_y$ that outputs $y$. Finally, output the tuple $(x,y)$. This program has length $K(x)+K(y)+c$. But it seems to me that there must be something wrong with this argument (and therefore also the exercise). Consider the computable function that concatenates two strings $f(x,y)=xy$. Then
$$K(xy)=K(f(x,y))\leq K(x,y)+c \leq K(x)+K(y)+c'.$$
But this contradicts the fact that for any constant $c$, there exist strings $x$ and $y$ such that
$$K(xy)>K(x)+K(y)+c.$$
This last fact is often stated (for example as an exercise in Sipser chapter 6).

I cannot formally prove the statement in Elements of Information Theory. Here is my attempt:

Let $D$ be the decompressor used in the definition of Kolmogorov complexity. Define $D'$ as
$$D'(z)=(D(p_x),D(p_y))=(x,y)$$ when $z$ encodes a 2-tuple, and never halting otherwise. We encode a tuple by repeating each bit in each element of the tuple and using 01 as a seperator. Then $$K_{D'}(x,y)\leq 2K(x)+2K(y)+c,$$ which implies that $K(x,y)\leq 2K(x)+2K(y)+c'$.

My question: Is the exercise in Elements of Information Theory wrong, or am I misunderstanding something?